# Pra que serve o Event.namespace do jQuery

Tags: jquery

Na [documentação do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), temos lá a explicação do `event.namespace`.

Isso permite utilizar um evento (ou criar um evento) específico do jQuery, 
com um namespace, através de um `.` ponto e um nome na frente desse evento.

Exemplo:

```
$(document).on('click.first_event', function (event)
{
     alert(event.namespace);
});
```

Gostaria de saber qual é a vantagem de utilizar eventos com esses `namespaces` no jQuery?

Pra que serve esses `namespaces`?

Comment: Observação: Não é uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47956/eventos-com-namespace

Comment: Não acho que seja uma duplicata, lá pergunta como replicar em javascript puro.

Comment: Mas o pessoal foi bem rápido pra marcar como duplicado. Eu também não concordo - senão nem teria perguntado.

Comment: Wallace não é bem uma mensagem pra ti, mas pra fila de analise, quando alguem for clicar pra fechar, vai ler o meu comentário junto a pergunta, assim coloco minha opinião de que isto não é uma duplicata, eu comentei pela fila de analise diretamente e marquei pra deixar aberta.

Answer (score 0):

Um `event.namespace` pode ser útil para controle de quais eventos específicos quero remover.

Exemplo:

Suponhamos que eu tenha três eventos de `scroll` vinculados a `window`.

Quero remover um deles especificamente, porém não todos.

Se eu fizesse assim:

```
$(window).scroll(function (){  
      alert('1');
   }

   $(window).scroll(function (){  
      alert('1');
   }

   $(window).off('scroll');
```

Eu removeria todos os eventos.

Porém se eu fizesse assim, eu conseguiria êxito, graças ao `event.namespace`.

```
$(window).bind('scroll.alert_1', function ()
{
     alert('1');
});

$(window).bind('scroll.alert_1', function ()
{
     alert('2');
});

$(window).unbind('scroll.alert_1');
```

No caso acima, só será exibido o `alert('2')`, já que consegui remover um evento específico por conta desse `namespace`.